# Why <s:if test> tag isn't working correctly?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, struts-tags

I've set a value in session (something) , now i can't use that in struts if tag

```
<s:if test=%{#session.key == 'something'}>
    // 'some code'
</s:if>
```

'some code' never runs..
but i can reach that specific value from the same key in the session in property tag correctly.

`<s:property value="#session.key" />`

any help ?

Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you try: `<s:if test="%{#session.key == 'something'}">`

Comment: there's no different

Comment: Print the value of #session.key, just above your if condition. If the syntax is correct then probably your if condition is not true.

Comment: read my question carefully please, i did what you say before i get my desire value and if condition should be true because printed value and equal value in if statement are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got solution.
problem is : the key which is in the session object is not a string and should be convert to string .

solution i found is : using `StrutsTypeConverter` for that value in a seperate class then, override two methods `convertToString`, `convertFromString` and do define `xwork-conversion.properties` file under `WEB-INF/classes` folder (configurations) and put `key = convertorClassName`in it.
so struts will automatically do conversion when needed.

if you have any easier solution for type casting, i'll be happy =)

Thanks!